# How can I use an MS Word drop down list to specifiy the range of an INCLUDETEXT?

Tags: drop-down-menu, ms-word, include

I have an MS Word drop down list with two elements, "Level 4" and "Optional". I want to use the selection to include a range of text from another document. I can get the selection of the drop down list using { REF List }. For example, I was able to get the following to work:

{ INCLUDETEXT "C:\event.docx" {REF Level}Cond }

when I choose "Optional". However when I choose "Level 4" I get a Bookmark not defined error, assumably because the INCLUDETEXT is looking for "Level 4Cond" and the bookmark in event.docx is "Level4Cond".

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this? I've thought about using the value of the drop down list rather than the display name but can't find any info on that. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use 'Level4' in the dropdown instead of 'Level 4'?

Comment: I wish I could. The drop down is actually part of a title at the top of the page.and I hand the page out to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your current {REF Level} field with a field coded as:

{IF{REF Level}= "Level 4" "Level4" "Optional"}

If there are more 'Level' entries (and possibly other kinds of text entries, too), you could use a field coded as:

{IF{REF Level}= "Level*" "Level{REF Level \# 0}" "{REF Level}"}.

Comment: If my menu grows would you suggest I use nested IF statements? I thought about using IF statement but was hoping for something easier. Thanks.